# Python3 exec() function not importing variables from other .py file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am migrating scripts from Python2.7 to Python3.6. I have a function that opens a python file and imports the variables. Works fine in 2.7 but in 3.6 I get an error and I can't figure out what the issue is.

Code:

```
def _load_rules(old_hash=''):
    # Determine if the rules file has changed, and if so reload it
    rules = open(rules_file, 'r').read()
    new_hash = md5(b'rules').hexdigest()
    if new_hash != old_hash:
        exec(rules)
        # C{ignore_rules} and C{notify_rules} come from the script execution
        return (new_hash, ignore_rules, notify_rules)
    return (old_hash, None, None)
```

This function checks the `rules.py` file to see if any changes were made and if not it runs `exec(rules)` which opens the `rules.py` file and should take in the variables `ignore_rules` and `notify_rules`, which are dictionaries of various "rules" for the purposes of these scripts. The `rules.py` file is formated like so.

```
import datetime
import re

notify_rules = \
        [{'event': 'failure',
          'access_point': None,
          'expression': re.compile(r'some_regex'),
          'addresses': ['some_email@email.com']},
     {'event': 'failure',
          'access_point': 'access_point_',
          'addresses': ['some_email@email.com']},

ignore_rules = \
        [{'access_point': 'something'},
         {'access_point': 'something'},
         {'access_point': 'something'},
         {'access_point': 'something'},]
```

Traceback:

```
File "/app/eam/gaic/ai_mon/monitoring.py", line 174, in _load_rules
            return (new_hash, notify_rules, ignore_rules)
        builtins.NameError: name 'notify_rules' is not defined
```

Comment: What's wrong with `from rules import new_hash, notify_rules, ignore_rules`? Or [importing the module dynamically](/questions/301134)? Also, just to make sure, you're aware that Python 2.7 is about as old as windows 7?

Comment: `exec()` supports the pass in of context if you check out the optional params.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am moving this code OFF of python 2.7 to 3.6... The issue I have is that the exec function in 2.7 worked as intended but in 3.6 it no longer works. It can't import the local variables from the rules.py file.

Comment: @iNeedScissors61 so, that code was relying on behavior that was explicitly warned against: modifications to `locals()` being reflected in the local namespace. Instead, explicitly create a namespace: `ns = {}`, then `exec(rules, ns)` then finally, `return (new_hash, ns["ignore_rules"], ns["notify_rules"])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was able to get the errors to stop and code to execute further by editing the line to `exec(rules, globals(), globals())`. I'm curious if that essentially does the same thing?

Comment: @iNeedScissors61 **no don't do that**. Don't just *polllute the global namespace*. You should use the explicitly namespace approach I showed you above